# Should there be a "Joel Spolsky" mentions badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, joel-spolsky

Should there be a badge for N instances of on-topic mentioning of Joel's name (SO, JoS, FogCreek, Joel's software, EBS, all count)?

I personally think such a tag would be Way Cool.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about implementing such tag, but may be some relevant sub-string searches in answers up-voted at least once?

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529385/how-to-write-technical-specs-for-a-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

But, if we must have it. We could call it "Golden Calf"

Comment: BTW: NO offense to Joel. I mention that dude in just about every other post on my blog. I'm as guilty of idolatry as anyone. =)

Answer (score 12):

Badges are supposed to be rewards for good behavior. Bleeting out Joel's name or his company's products isn't good (or necessarily bad) behavior.

Comment: P.S. Although not all badges seem aimed at promiting good behavior. "Tumbleweed"?

Comment: Tumbleweed is a consolation badge.

Answer (score 5):

The Badge should look like some pieces of a badge duct-taped together though.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, will invoke Joel when the spirit moves me.  However, I could see a badge triggering a rash of name dropping in order to trigger such a badge.  In the end, although the intention is good, it might not have the desired effect - it might end up weakening any reference to the Joel trademark.

Comment: A valid concern, although this is as easy/hard to game as a lot of other badges (300 votes? I saw every answer on a many-answer Q up-voted twice despite pretty much every A being useless or wrong). 
Probably harder to game than many badges if it requires the answer to be up-voted at least once or twice to count.